# ADSL router setup help

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, wireless-networking, adsl-router

I recently bought a Tenda W548D ADSL wireless router/modem but can't get it to automatically connect to the internet (so that when I connect my laptop to it using wireless, my laptop is connected to the internet too)?

Update: the device shows up on the Wireless connections but I need to connect to the wireless network first, then connect to the internet manually using the wirelessLAN.

Operating system is Windows Vista.

Comment: We really need more information than this to be helpful to you.

Comment: @KronoS- the device shows up on the Wireless connections but I need to connect to the wireless network first, then connect to the internet manually using the wirelessLAN. I'm using Vista

Answer (score -1):

You may need to register the equipment with your ISP.  Specifically the model number and the MAC Address.

Comment: I've already installed a wired router before without registering anything with the ISP so that probably isn't the problem here.

Comment: What ISPs have you been using?

Comment: @Ciaran- Nepal Telecom(http://ntc.com.np/) and here's the link to the ADSL tech-support page- http://ntc.com.np/internet/adsl/adsl_cpeConf.php; I'll post screenshots if you ask for them

Comment: It's working now. I went through the quick setup again and it worked :D. Thanks!!!